# How to delete certain rows in plsql

Tags: sql, plsql, delete-row

I have the following problem with two tables:

table1 has

- uid
- name

table2 has

- id
- name

I want to write a sql script that deletes all rows from table1 which don't meet the condition

```
table1.uid = table2.id
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 where id = t1.uid)
```

OR

```
delete from table1
where uid not in (select id from table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( select table2.name
  from table2
  where table1.uid = table2.id);
```